# I have been trying to understand operator precedence but got stuck in this question

Tags: operator-precedence

I have been trying to understand operator precedence but got stuck in this question.Here is the code:

```
int i=1;
int a= ++i + ++i + ++i * i++ + i++;
```

When I calculate using pen and paper, I am getting 26 as the value of a (2+3+4*4+5 => 2+3+16+5 = 26).But when I compile it I am getting 31 as the output.

Could somebody please help me with this.

Comment: I don't know what language you are using but in C# the result is 26.

Comment: I used c++ sir @Johan Donne